# how to limit mapview to show just a specific city?

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

i have seen the method `mapView.setScrollableAreaLimit(bBox)` for limiting the mapview to specific area .
now my question is how to limit mapview to a specific city? eg: Paris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to determine the bounding box for Paris, e.g. by using a [geocoder](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Search_engines) like [Nominatim](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim).

Comment: thanks , i am new to osm . can you explain it a bit more ?

Comment: Here is an [example Nominatim query for Paris](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=Paris&format=json&polygon_geojson=1&limit=1). It returns a polygon, not a bbox. To get a bbox you have to go through the list of points and collect the most northeast, northwest, southeast and southwest points.

Comment: do you mean convert this List to List of BoundingBoxE6 ? then how to apply this List to mapview?

Comment: Yes. Iterate through all the points in the polygon. Store the min/max for north, east, south and west for calculating the corresponding north-east and south-west bounds, create your BoundingBoxE6 object and voilà.